# Which is the conformal factor of $S^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory

I'm confused about Conformal factor. All 2D riemannian manifolds are conformally flat. That means, if $g$ is the metric, exists a *scalar* function $\Omega$ that
$g_{a,b}=\Omega^2 \delta_{a,b}$
In the case of geographical coordinates
$$g_{a,b}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & sin^2\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & sin^2\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}=\Omega^2 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Which is the conformal factor in this case? It doesn't seem a simple scalar and couldn't be $g=\Omega^2$.
How to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a  sphere of radius $R$
$$
ds^2= \frac {4R^2(dx^2+dy^2)}{(R^2+x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac {4R^2dz d\bar z}{(R^2+|z|^2)^2}
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are stereographc coordinates. If you set $z= x+iy=e^{i\phi} \tan (\theta/2)$ then $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the usual spherical coordinates on the sphere.

So
$$
\Omega^2= \frac{4R^2}{(R^2+x^2+y^2)^2}.
$$

Comment: and so
$ds^2 = d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi =  4R^2/(R^2 +r)(dx^2 + dy^2)$

Thanks, very clear.

I also read this link

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920691/stereographic-projection-is-conformal-from-the-line-element

Comment: $ds^2 = d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2 =  4R^2/(R^2 +r^2)(dx^2 + dy^2)$